# How to avoid converting model to Traced-model every time in YOLOv7?

Tags: python, yolov7

I am using [YOLOv7](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) for object detection. When I run the following command, object detection works fine:

```
python detect.py --weights yolov7.pt --conf 0.25 --img-size 640 --source inference/images/horses.jpg
```

However, every time I run this command, the model is converted to a Traced-model, which takes a few seconds.

```
Model Summary: 306 layers, 36905341 parameters, 6652669 gradients
 Convert model to Traced-model... 
 traced_script_module saved! 
 model is traced!
```

Object detection takes only around 1 second. How can I avoid converting the model every time and just perform object detection?

I tried setting the output traced_model.pt as the weights, but I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'RecursiveScriptModule' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use --no-trace attribute in command. See the arguments passed in detect.py (probably line 185) in code.